# Undefined variable: _Post

Tags: php

My email password script is showing error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _Post in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DreamWeaver\EMPWScript.php on line 3 Fail - Please try
>   again!

I define the variable, what is wrong?

```
<?php
    @session_start();
    $_SESSION['EMPW'] = $_Post['Email1'];
?>
```

Comment: whenever you use `$_Post['Email1']` apply `isset($_Post['Email1'])? $_Post['Email1']:''`

Comment: `$_POST`. all caps.

Comment: check  Email1 maybe you've mistyped it

Answer (score 4):

You wrote:

```
$_SESSION['EMPW'] = $_Post['Email1'];
```

but PHP is case sensitive, so try this:

```
 $_SESSION['EMPW'] = $_POST['Email1'];
```

(In other words, `POST` has to be uppercase).

Answer (score 0):

You can never be sure if it is POST or which variable type it is, so it could be better to always check and cast to the expected type.

```
$empw = (string) ($_POST['email] ?? '');
//here would be nice to throw some exception if email empty
$_SESSION['EMPW'] = $_POST['Email1'];
```